# Insert a link to a drawing in a document using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying insert a link to a drawing in a google doc.

I want the code to give the same result as the following inputs :

**1. Open document**

**2. insert**

**3. drawing**

**4. from drive**

**5. link to source**

My code simply puts the drawing in the document without linking it to the original

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('documentID');
  var drawing = DriveApp.getFileById('drawingID');

  var drawingId = drawing.getId();
  var image = Drive.Files.get(drawingId);
  var imageBlob = getBlob(image.exportLinks['image/jpeg']);

  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendImage(imageBlob);
}

function getBlob(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
  return response.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: Try `var img=body.appendImage(imageBlob);img.setLinkUrl(image.exportLinks['image/jpeg'])`

Comment: thanks for the reply. the image gets properly linked to the drawing but changes to the original drawing aren't reflected in the drawing that's in the google document

Comment: @Walid Jabari I cannot understand about your current issue. Can I ask you more information of about ``changes to the original drawing aren't reflected in the drawing that's in the google document``?

Comment: @Tanaike So basically if you insert a drawing to a document using the standard method (the one described in the post), you have the option to link the original drawing to the one you're inserting. That way, if you make any changes to the original drawing, they will apply to the drawing that's on the document.

I'm trying to emulate that using apps script

Comment: @Walid Jabari Thank you for replying. I could understand about what you want to do. Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for putting the Drawing file in Class DocumentApp and Docs API, yet. So I think that in the current stage, it cannot achieve what you want to do, yet. I apologize that I couldn't find the workaround for achieving it.

Comment: @Tanaike Ok thanks anyway. I will try to find a work around

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do that as of now.

I found a work around which consists of changing the script of document by adding an update function.

```
function main(e) 
{
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var allImage = doc.getBody().getImages();
  if(allImage.length != 0)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < allImage.length; i++)
    {
      update(doc, allImage[i]);
    }
  }
}

function update(doc, image)
{
  var drawingUrl = image.getLinkUrl();

  if(drawingUrl != null)
  {
    var drawing = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(drawingUrl));
    var drawingId = drawing.getId();

    image.removeFromParent();

    var newImage = Drive.Files.get(drawingId);
    var imageBlob = getBlob(newImage.exportLinks['image/jpeg']);

    var body = doc.getBody();
    body.appendImage(imageBlob).setLinkUrl(drawingUrl);
  }
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) 
{ 

  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
}

function getBlob(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
  return response.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: yes, the function will update every image in a document that has a link to an external file